# How to determine multimedia component is published to filesystem or database

Tags: tridion

How can we determine whether multimedia components are published to filesystem or database?

Under which situation does the green color globe appear on any published component?

Answer (score 10):

The green globe will appear on any published component if the component's schema is associated with template that supports dynamic publishing.

You can not determine on from CMS server where your dynamic component presentation will be stored.

Answer (score 7):

The globe will show on any Component that has been published using a Component Template which supports Dynamic publishing (i.e. The Component has been published as a Dynamic Component Presentation).

Regarding your second question, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way from the CM side to know if the item has been published to the Broker Database or File System using a out of the box SDL Tridion API. However, as suggested by @Alvin, it is possible to do extend the existing storage layers as documented in this great article by @Puf http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx

Comment: I can confirm that Chris. How the deployer chooses to store the binaries is its own business!

Comment: Unless Mr. (Frank) P tells it otherwise! ;-) [See his Tridionworld article](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx) on how to extend Tridion to be aware of multimedia server status.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell whether an item will be published to file system or database by analysing the content delivery configuration on the relevant publication target. If your logging is suitably configured, you will see evidence there of the deployment.

As for whether you can detect the distinction on the content manager: No, you can't, and you shouldn't need to. The only people for whom it would be relevant are those with knowledge of the inner workings of your web applications, and presumably these people are able to discover the details of the content delivery configuration. For content workers such as web editors, it is sufficient to know that the item was published successfully or otherwise. This is one of the main benefits of a web content management system: content workers can deal with an abstraction of the web site, and not with its actual inner workings.

A page or component will be displayed using the "published" icon if that page or component is currently published to any of the publication targets. One is sufficient, so in practice, relying on the icon is not always very informative. For a detailed view, pull up the where-used dialog for that item and select the Published To tab. This will tell you which targets the item is currently published to.